# Error using \variation command in the skak package

Tags: chess, skak

I'm using the `skak` package to write and comment a chess match.

Trouble occurs when you use the command `\variation` to analyze the possible consequences to vary the move 15. This `MWE` code generates an error if i uncomment the commented lines (lines 16 and 17), but i want to type this explanation.

The command `\variation` already has been used before (in the code) without problems.

Here my code

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{skak}
\begin{document}
\newgame
\noindent\mainline{1.e4 c6 2.d4 d5 3.Nd2 dxe4 4.Nxe4 Nd7 5.Ng5 Ngf6 6.Bc4 e6 7.Qe2 Nb6 8.Bb3 h6 9.N5f3 c5} (\variation{9...a5}) \mainline{10.Bf4 Bd6 11.Bg3 Qe7}
(it's also possible \variation{11...Qc7} and \variation{11...O-O})
\mainline{12.dxc5 Bxc5 13.Ne5 Bd7 14.Ngf3 Nh5}
(no \variation{14...O-O-O 15.Nxf7 Qxf7 16.Qe5}).\\
\begin{center}
\showboard
\end{center}
\styleC
\mainline{15.O-O-O Nxg3}
Change this move by \variation{15...O-O-O} allows 
%\variation{16.Nxd7 Nxd7 17.Bc5!}
%and if \variation{17...Nxe5?!}, then \variation{18.Nxe5 Nf4 19.Qc4}, giving an advantage.
\mainline{16.hxg3 O-O-O}
\end{document}
```

As I said before if i uncomment the lines get an error message like this

> []
>
> ! mainline: 16 is not the correct move number.
>    ...: 16 is not the correct move number}
>
> l.15 \variation{16.Nxd7 Nxd7 17.Bc5!}
>
> This error message was generated by an \errmessage
>   command, so I can't give any explicit help.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm almost sure that this code worked in a previous version of `skak` package but i don't remember which was.

Comment: In the current `skak` `\variation` "plays" the moves too (so that longmoves works) and so move numbers are important. If you want to continue a variation you will have to use one of the continuation commands (in your case `\continuevariationcurrent`) see refman.pdf. xskak hasn't this problem as variations are no played (and it has more possibilities to play more than one game).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i'm modifying the code to use your package `xskak`, the commands are a bit different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change skak to xskak it works fine.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}
\newgame
\noindent\mainline{1.e4 c6 2.d4 d5 3.Nd2 dxe4 4.Nxe4 Nd7 5.Ng5 Ngf6 6.Bc4 e6 7.Qe2 Nb6 8.Bb3 h6 9.N5f3 c5} (\variation{9...a5}) \mainline{10.Bf4 Bd6 11.Bg3 Qe7}
(it's also possible \variation{11...Qc7} and \variation{11...O-O})
\mainline{12.dxc5 Bxc5 13.Ne5 Bd7 14.Ngf3 Nh5}
(no \variation{14...O-O-O 15.Nxf7 Qxf7 16.Qe5}).\\
\begin{center}
\showboard
\end{center}
\styleC
\mainline{15.O-O-O Nxg3}
Change this move by \variation{15...O-O-O} allows \variation{16.Nxd7 Nxd7 17.Bc5!}
\mainline{16.hxg3 O-O-O}

%and if \variation{17...Nxe5?!}, then \variation{18.Nxe5 Nf4 19.Qc4}, giving an advantage.
\end{document}
```